# Android Layout Overflow Concern

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I was doing a quick mockup for a song_item.xml file that will go into a listView.

The first picture is the desired "output", however, if the song title is too long, then it will overflow into the second line; hiding the group name!

So the second picture is NOT the desired "output"

**What are ways to overcome this**, and then

*** * MAYBE * *** has Google stated why there are only 3 layout choices? Match Parent, Fill Parent, and Wrap Content? Why not some layout abilities for "stationary overflows". You see people programmatically create solutions that achieve things like scrolling textViews, etc...

[image]
[image]

---

**Based on suggestion from user1374864 (the accepted answer)**

This is the output that occurs with the input from the second picture, but uses a modified versions of user1374864's answer. I might decide to go with the marquee, but for right now...this is good!

[image]

Comment: This can be done with RelativeLayout. The song title should have WRAP_CONTENT for the height parameters and the second line should use android:layout_below="@id/song_title_id"

Comment: @prijupaul I will try that, but won't that do the exact same thing! If the title of the song is too long, it will wrap to the second line...pushing the group name away again?

Comment: ideally, you list item view will grow to contain the entire view. So don't hardcode the height of the parent layout. So its long text, the item height will be larger compared to other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following lines to the Textview of the song title.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

It forces your TextView to be only a singleline and marquee the text if it is too long.

Comment: This seems to do what I was wanting! I will remember to look more at the attributes of the controls before posting here. The SingleLine attribute is definitely what I should have seen