# Custom Adapter for ListView with semi-complex list item

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make an Activity that basically holds a list on song items that are "semi-complex." The output of one list item can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838693/android-layout-overflow-concern). I found what seemed like a good example online to follow to create such a thing, and that could is below.

However, ArrayAdapters apparently can only be used on SIMPLE TextViews (this is basically the error I am getting from the LogCat), and I have 3 TextViews I have to control and the color in one of them along with an image. So the code will not compile. I have looked into ListAdapters, but the underlining structure is completely different from the ArrayAdapter is is far from a 1 to 1 translation to it.

**What should I do, and use? I am lost right now!**

FYI, in the LogCat I get the following (NOTE I removed the LogCat code from the code below...that was put in right AFTER the super call in the constructor of SimpleSongAdapter)...

[image]

Here is my `SimpleSongAdapter` class

```
public class SimpleSongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleSong> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceID;
    SimpleSong song[] = null;

    public SimpleSongAdapter(Context context, int resource, SimpleSong[] data) {
        super(context, resource, data);

        this.layoutResourceID = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.song = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View row = convertView;
        SimpleSongHolder songHolder = null;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater newView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = newView.inflate(this.layoutResourceID, parent, false);

            ExtractLayoutResources(parent, row, songHolder);

            row.setTag(songHolder);

        } else {

            songHolder = (SimpleSongHolder) row.getTag();

        }

        SetLayoutResource(songHolder, position);

        return row;

    }

    private void SetLayoutResource(SimpleSongHolder songHolder, int position) {

        SimpleSong currentSong = song[position];

        songHolder.imgSongThumbnail.setImageResource(currentSong.thumbnail);
        songHolder.txtSongName.setText(currentSong.songName);
        songHolder.txtGroupName.setText(currentSong.groupName);

        String metaText = "";
        int colorID = 0;

        // switch statement to set metaText and colorID

        songHolder.txtSongMetaInfo.setText(metaText);
        songHolder.txtSongMetaInfo.setTextColor(colorID);
    }

    private void ExtractLayoutResources(ViewGroup parent, View row, SimpleSongHolder songHolder) {

        songHolder = new SimpleSongHolder();

        songHolder.imgSongThumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgSongThumbnail);
        songHolder.txtSongName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
        songHolder.txtGroupName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtGroupName);
        songHolder.txtSongMetaInfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSongMetaInfo);

    }

    private static class SimpleSongHolder {

        ImageView imgSongThumbnail;
        TextView txtSongName;
        TextView txtGroupName;
        TextView txtSongMetaInfo;

    }
}
```

In `SimpleSong` class I have

```
public class SimpleSong {

public int thumbnail;
    public String songName;
    public String groupName;
    public String songMetaInfo;

    public RemixType remixType;

    public SimpleSong(String songName, String groupName) {

        this.songName = songName;
        this.groupName = groupName;

    }

// Sets to set other attributes
```

In `MainActivity` I have

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SimpleSong songs[] = new SimpleSong[] { 
            // new SimpleSong mock object list
        };

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songView);

        View listHeader = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
        SimpleSongAdapter songAdapter = new SimpleSongAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, songs);

        listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);
        listView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify....the problem seems to be the use of ArrayAdapter. I am trying to get more info on the LogCat errors right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking this constructor:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

Which expects the resource id to be the id of a `TextView`, but you are passing the id of the layout.

You need to use the following constructor in stead:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

And call it like:

```
SimpleSongAdapter songAdapter = new SimpleSongAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, 0, songs);
```

Comment: I got it to work another way (using a BaseAdapter), but would this work still? I have 3 different TextViews that need to be populated...and one of them needs there text color modified.

Comment: BaseAdapter should be the ideal way to go. This should still work provided as we are ignoring the textview parameter and populating the 3 textviews in getView.I haven't tried this solution but just my thought.

Comment: I posted another question that relates to this one, but is with the layout issues....not a lot of activity on it right now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884937/android-custom-control-layout-troubles