# Android Custom Control Layout Troubles

Tags: android, xml, layout, custom-controls

I have built a custom listView xml item; however, I am not getting what I expected...I changed the background colors to show in more detail what is happening on the second picture.

Basically, the playlist items should extend to the right side of the screen, and the colored text should be all on the right side of the screen (That is what the Designer is showing). Right now the colored text lines up right where the song title ends.

**How do I fix this?**

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image: Expected Result]

**WHAT I AM GETTING!**

[image: What I am getting]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgSongThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:src="@drawable/crayonpop_barbarbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSongName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#DDD" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGroupName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/group"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#DDD" 
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSongMetaInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="@string/meta_data"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based I reworked my code to follow a hybrid `LinearLayout` x `RelativeLayout` scheme before I noticed a bunch of answers pop up here. @yahya was the almost identical to what I came up with, so I accepted that answer, as that answer really took into account the precise layout that I presented in the photos above with attention on reducing the use of a lot of margin code.

The following is what my code (which again is very similar to @yahya 's answer below) looks like on my phone. Go ahead...look up these songs and enjoy ;)

[image]

Comment: NOTE: The XML on the bottom correlates to the EXPECTED RESULT image

Comment: I would prefer this XML layout to be left basically how it is laid out now...but if that IS why this problem is occurring, then I can deal with a different layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your layout, and reduce used embedded layouts to improve your view hierarc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgSongThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:src="@drawable/crayonpop_barbarbar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSongName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#DDD" />

        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSongName"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:gravity="right" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSongMetaInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="@string/meta_data"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGroupName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/group" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#DDD" 
                android:singleLine="true" />  

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With the suggestion from @prijupaul earlier, I decided to create on that followed the `RelativeLayout`, and created one that worked for me! Your code is really close to what I ended up with after a lot of trial and error. So I will accept your answer. However, your code does have a slight error with swapping `txtGroupName` and `txtSongMetaInfo`. Also I did not put a `LinearLayout` within my `RelativeLayout`, just laid them out relatively ;)

Comment: Yeah, i thought also after i posted my answer :) Glad that you find your solution though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. With RelativeLayout, you can align the components based on other components.

In this case,

The main textview with id txtSongName, should take width as match_parent.

`txtGroupName` should use `layout_botton=@id/txtSongName`

and `txtSongMetaInfo` should use `layout_torightof=@id/txtGroupName` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Doing this the main advantages are reduced number layouts and hence better performance.

Comment: Yeah...I was thinking about going with Relative layout....but was not really sure with `txtSongMetaInfo` on how to align that. But the bigger issue I have is that it seems like my current code should work!

I will probably do the relative layout, but would like an answer to why mine does not work now

Comment: I did go along with the `RelativeLayout`; however, that was with a hitch!  I still used the `LinearLayout` on the top-level, and put the image and then a `RelativeLayout`. That was because I wanted to simplify the use of margins in the XML, and creating a top-level `RelativeLayout` was a nightmare trying to fix the small problems that popped up. However, yours was post set me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes your solution, just copy the below code it will suit your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/vw_grey_btn" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since my reputation is low am not able to attach my screen shot :

Comment: In the last few hours, I have been working on this, and came up with a solution that worked for me. I was also focusing A LOT on the aesthetic presentation of the components to. I did a quick copy-paste into my code, and the IDE designer shows that this might work; however, I did not feel like changing the ID's and text, etc.. so I did not test it on my mobile device. I first tried the `ImageView` within the `RelativeLayout`, but did not like the results (aesthetically), so I did something very similar to @yahya answer above. I up'd this post because it does seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the weight on your ImageView, change the weight of your FrameLayout to 1 and width to 0dp, that should do it. But still, like @prijupaul suggested, use RelativeLayout to reduce the number of views, especially when its inside a ListView.  BTW, I'd recommend you to take a look at this tool: [jimulabs.com](http://jimulabs.com).

Comment: I tried all of this (except changing the `width` to `0dp`)! I had no luck with that then....I was really hoping this `0dp` change was going to work....but it leads to the same problem as above! Unless, I made some other changes after posting the original code that made this not work

Answer (score 0):

What is your code for inflating the layout?

You should be inflating using something like this (assuming you are using a BaseAdapter)

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXX, parent, false);
```

If you pass null as the ViewGroup root when you inflate, it will ignore the fill_parent/match_parent parameters of the root layout and set it to wrap_content, giving you the result you were getting.

Even though it looks like you've got the layout you wanted, you should ensure you are still inflating it correctly.

Comment: If you check out the `Linked` post `Custom Adapter for ListView with semi-complex list item`, you will see what code I basically had before. It looks like I have what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this entire layout could be done with many fewer views by putting all of the children inside of a single RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#333" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSongThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/crayonpop_barbarbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSongName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgSongThumbnail"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#DDD" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGroupName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtSongName"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtSongName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Sistar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#DDD" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSongMetaInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtGroupName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtSongName"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Remix #1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```